# What portions of JavaScript classes are recreated in memory when I call `new`?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, memory-footprint

I have a constructor in JavaScript like this:

```
function Foo() {

  var privateProperty = "goodbye";
  this.publicProperty = "hello";

  function privateMethod() {

    return "Shhhhh";
  }
  this.publicMethod = function publicMethod() {

    return "extroverted";
  };
}

Foo.prototype.youCanSeeMe = "I'm out here";
Foo.prototype.typical = function typical() {

  return "look at me out here";
};

var b = new Foo();
var c = new Foo();
```

In the latest version of the v8 JavaScript engine, which properties of my class are copied in memory? I mean, are there now two copies of `privateProperty`, `publicProperty`, `privateMethod`, and so on in memory?

If the memory footprint of `b` was 100 bytes, would the memory footprint of `b` and `c` together be 200 bytes? Bigger, smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your class constructor will exist as copies in memory while everything in Foo.prototype will be shared between instances. Hence the memory footprint should be slightly less than 200 bytes

For reference see the excellent MDN [Javascript Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) article where they explain how a property is accessed in javascript

Comment: could you please cite some sources for this information?

Comment: @elmalto This is because the constructor is a closure?

Comment: @zzzzBov It's easy to reason this; changing the prototype afterwards affects both instances, thus it lives in its own part of memory and the other instances reference it.

Comment: @Nope Foo.prototype is itself an object and b and c only reference Foo.prototype. When you look for a property it looks in the object itself first and then goes up the prototype chain and sees that it exists in Foo.prototype

Comment: This answer is over-simplistic and I doubt there is one that would hold for every JavaScript engine in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @elmalto I see. So, `privateProperty`, `publicProperty`, `privateMethod`, and `publicMethod` are all copied in memory, because they are in their own closure. ( As evidenced by changing the value of `a.publicProperty` and noting its value is now different from `b.publicProperty`. ) Meanwhile, `a.prototype === b.prototype === ` the object created when `new` was called. Furthermore, that object was decorated by calling `Foo()`. Correct? Clear as mud?

Comment: @plalx I'll add an engine and version number.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I'm well aware of how the prototype chain works. What I asked for were sources that indicate how the JavaScript engine *actually* handles memory, not just a guess at how they might be structured.

Comment: @zzzzBov I am not 100% familiar with V8's hidden class system, but from my understanding even in hidden classes the values of each object's properties should be stored separately for fast mapping and the prototype is still an extra class. What the exact memory consumption of any of these classes would be is above me